# Problem getting return from api with axios

Tags: reactjs, jwt, axios

Im trying to get a token with jsonwebtoken from my api to my react component but i cannot get it from the client side however I guess everything server side seems ok.

API :

```
router.post("/api/user/login", async (ctx, next) => {
  var nickname = ctx.request.body.data.nickname;
  var password = ctx.request.body.data.password;
  var user = await db.collection("tmp_users").find({nickname: nickname}).toArray();
  var token = "";

  if (user.length > 0) {
    const hashPassword = user[0].password;
    bcrypt.compare(password, hashPassword)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        jwt.sign({ user: user}, "test", (err, res) => {
          console.log("token GOOD => ", res);
          ctx.body = res;
          return res;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  console.log("token FAILED => ", token);
  ctx.body = token;
  return token;
});
```

and here there is the part of the client side with axios :

```
axios.post("/api/user/login", { data })
.then(res => {
  console.log("res =>", res);
  console.log("res data =>", res.data);
  console.log("res token => ", res.token);
  console.log("res data token =>", res.data.token);
});
```

the question is : where can I find the token ? in the server side the log console is OK. but client side i'm lost, I can't find it.

Maybe I didnt get something ?
thanks for help !

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever actually return anything on the server side. What framework are you using server side?

Comment: yeah sorry, but even if i return, i dont get anything

Comment: just return the promise

Comment: I'm using koa, when you want to return you use "ctx.body = value" it's equivalent to "res.json()" with express

Comment: I try "return res" it doesnt work too anyway ...

Comment: it's the callback that is giving you issues. Your function returns before the token is available to be added to the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not returning any value because you are returning inside promise which is asynchronous. 
I have written the alternative approach which libraries( bcrypt/jwt) provide for synchronous operation.

```
router.post("/api/user/login", async (ctx, next) => {
  var nickname = ctx.request.body.data.nickname;
  var password = ctx.request.body.data.password;
  var user = await db.collection("tmp_users").find({nickname: nickname}).toArray();
  var token = "";
  if (user.length > 0) {
    const hashPassword = user[0].password;
    const res = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashPassword);
    if (res) {
      const jwttoken = await jwt.sign({ user: user}, "test")
      console.log("token GOOD => ", jwttoken);
      ctx.body = jwttoken;
      return jwttoken;
    }
  }
  return new Error("Error");
});
```

Comment: I would just add one word of caution. It is frowned upon to do any synchronous work in a node type environment. `bcrypt.compareSync` is a blocking function. Instead replace it with its asynchronous alternative such as `const res = await bcrypt.compare(password, hashPassword);` Here is a link on the issue of blocking https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/

Comment: Thank you @skellertor for the suggestion. I have updated it.